# DHT and NodeMCU completely not working?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I directly copy-pasted the dht.md example from the official NodeMCU GitHub into my Script window like so:

[image]

But upon saving to ESP8266 I get an error:

```
init.lua:3: attempt to index global 'dht' (a nil value)
```

Comment: Please refrain from begging - [the community discussed this recently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which NodeMcu firmware (version) do you use?
Make sure you get (build) the latest (1.5.1), easiest to get it from here:
http://nodemcu-build.com/

And -make sure- you click the little box saying 'DHT' there.

Comment: Using esplorer.ru is there any way I can download just DHT for that?

Comment: No, you need DHT compiled into the firmware.
The only option is to use the build service to compile a new firmware, which includes it, and then to re-flash that onto the ESP.

Comment: This site gave me a binary file, is there another site available that would give me the firmware in a better format?

Comment: I'm affraid that firmware only comes in a binary format.
I assume you originally flashed your ESP? Didn't that use a binary file?

Comment: You want to use these instructions to flash it: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/flash/

Comment: You want to flash that binary (what's the file name?) to address 0x00000, This tool: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-flasher/tree/master/Win32/Release is probably the easiest to use for that, you probably want to read these instructions also: https://learn.adafruit.com/building-and-running-micropython-on-the-esp8266/flash-firmware, and you will need to set your ESP in flash mode, which requires pulling the right pins up/down, if your ESP doesn't have a flash button